# How to have List Box contents dynamically depending on another List Box Selection in Excel - VBA user forms?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have primary data ( not static may change during other run time modules )
in one column and then I have columns for every element of primary column .

Say primary as A then if A has 3 elements then columns B , C and D will be the secondary columns having various rows of data.

In user form I have two List Box 1 & 2 .If user selects 2nd element in ListBox1 the ListBox2 displays contents of "C" column .

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim X As Integer
Dim vCol As Variant
Dim srange As Range
Dim ssheeet As Worksheet
Set ssheeet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
X = ListBox1.ListIndex
Me.ListBox1.List = ssheeet.Columns(X + 1).Values* 
             '2nd selection i.e., 2+1 gives 3rd -> "C" column 
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ssheeet As Worksheet
Set ssheeet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!A:A"
End Sub
```

**Query ?**

`Me.ListBox1.List = ssheeet.Columns(X + 1).Values`  is not working where i have to give dynamic range to the 2nd list box .
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall work:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim vCol As Variant
    Dim srange As Range
    Dim ssheeet As Worksheet
    Set ssheeet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    X = ListBox1.ListIndex
    Me.ListBox2.RowSource = ssheeet.Columns(X + 1).Address
End Sub
```

You can only push an array into List property, so it comes to

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim vCol As Variant
    Dim srange As Range
    Dim ssheeet As Worksheet
    Set ssheeet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    X = ListBox1.ListIndex

    Dim myArray() as variant
    myArray = ssheeet.Columns(X + 1).Values
    Me.ListBox2.List = myArray
End Sub
```

I've tested this method and it push all values including `Blank` into ListBox2. Not a good one, unless we determine the data range first.

Comment: 1.I am getting run time error 438 as Object does not support this property or method in   
    myArray = ssheeet.Columns(X + 1).Values .
2. About the range thing , I have number of rows in "X+1 " column , say cell(2,2) gives me the number of rows in X+1 column . Please Help